# How to loop over multiple pages of a website using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Hello everybody out there!
I have been working with BeautifulSoup for my scraping projects. Currently, I'm learning Scrapy. I have written a code in BeautifulSoup to loop over multiple pages of a single website using for loops. I looped over 10 pages and fetched URLs of blog posts from those pages using the code below. I want to do the same thing in Scrapy but can't figure out how. Can the same approach (code) be used with scrapy to do the same thing?
Here is the BeautifulSoup code:

```
 URL = 'https://www.brookings.edu/topic/environment/page/'
 lis=[]
 for page in range(1,10):

 req = requests.get(URL + str(page) + '/?type=posts')

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'lxml')
links = [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('a', 
href=re.compile('^(https://www.brookings.edu/blog/)'))]

links=list(set(links))

lis.append(links)
```

This piece of code fetched the links from 10 pages of the website. I stored these links (blog posts links) in the list named li outside the for loop. Then with another for loop on that finalList I wrote my code to extract the text from blog posts.

Comment: can you show your expected output

Comment: Scrapy can't render JS pages! that site is using JS

Comment: @Bhavya Parikh The above piece of code in BeautifulSoup is only extracting links from the ten web pages of that website. Output is only a list containing around 100 href links.

Comment: @ahmed I guess I'll have to use Selenium in that case. That code is just to give an idea of what I want to do with Scrapy.

Comment: @AngryKid In Scrapy you can use start_urls, you can assign start_urls = [] and put a list of URLs there instead of [].

Comment: what about `threading` can you try out with that or `multiprocessing`

Comment: Update your question with the failed attempt that you made while using scrapy. You must not expect someone to create a script anew using scrapy, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import scrapy


class BrSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'br'
    allowed_domains = ['brookings.edu']

    def start_requests(self):
        for page in range(1, 11):
            yield scrapy.Request(f'https://www.brookings.edu/topic/environment/page/{page}/?type=posts')

    def parse(self, response):
        for i in response.css('.title a::attr(href)'):
            yield {
                'Link': i.get()
            }
```

Output:

```
[
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2018/12/10/3-big-societal-problems-to-fix-in-2019/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/brookings-now/2018/10/31/highlights-an-energy-industry-view-on-moving-toward-a-lower-carbon-future/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/brown-center-chalkboard/2018/10/30/climate-confusion-content-and-strategies-not-controversy-are-the-biggest-challenges-for-science-teachers/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/fixgov/2018/10/25/the-economics-and-politics-of-carbon-pricing/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2018/10/11/climate-reality-requires-starting-at-home-weaning-from-fossil-fuels/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/techtank/2018/10/05/sharing-digitized-dna-sequences-must-balance-scientific-progress-with-fair-use/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2018/07/21/africa-in-the-news-eac-trade-statistics-nelson-mandela-day-and-conservation-updates/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2018/07/06/the-sustainable-development-goals-and-climate-finance-catalytic-agent-or-empty-vessel/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2018/06/14/enhancing-the-attractiveness-of-private-investment-in-hydropower-in-africa/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2018/06/01/trump-tried-to-kill-the-paris-agreement-but-the-effect-has-been-the-opposite/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2021/02/23/transforming-natural-resource-governance-break-silos-sharpen-politics/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2021/02/09/its-critical-that-we-invest-in-better-global-weather-and-climate-observations/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2021/02/04/secular-stagnation-climate-action-and-the-natural-rate-of-interest/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2021/01/27/figures-of-the-week-carbon-taxes-can-fuel-green-economic-recovery-and-reduce-income-inequality/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2021/01/25/to-support-climate-action-growth-measures-should-count-planetary-damages/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2021/01/25/the-national-security-imperative-to-tackle-illegal-unreported-and-unregulated-fishing/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2021/01/15/time-to-pivot-the-role-of-the-energy-transition-and-investors-in-forging-resilient-resource-rich-country-outcomes/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/education-plus-development/2019/12/10/national-climate-strategies-are-forgetting-about-girls-children-and-youth/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2021/05/15/africa-in-the-news-wildlife-horn-of-africa-and-infrastructure-updates/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2021/05/10/barriers-to-achieving-us-climate-goals-are-more-political-than-technical/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2020/12/15/the-trump-administrations-major-environmental-deregulations/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2021/01/14/disrupting-the-waste-management-industry-through-technology-insights-from-rubicon/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/fixgov/2020/12/28/who-is-and-isnt-represented-in-environmental-oversight-in-congress/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2020/12/17/regulating-autonomous-vehicles-and-ridesharing-lessons-from-california/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2019/12/09/building-an-ambitious-us-climate-policy-from-the-bottom-up/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2019/12/02/top-emitters-must-commit-to-a-u-turn-at-cop25/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/brown-center-chalkboard/2019/11/20/how-exposure-to-pollution-affects-educational-outcomes-and-inequality/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2019/10/03/a-conversation-with-guinean-president-conde-on-natural-resource-management-in-africa/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/the-avenue/2019/09/24/how-a-scrappy-federal-it-program-can-be-a-model-for-us-climate-action/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2019/09/17/success-from-the-un-climate-summit-will-hinge-on-new-ways-to-build-national-action/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2019/09/16/the-invisible-water-crisis/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2021/05/10/republicans-in-congress-are-out-of-step-with-the-american-public-on-climate/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2021/05/05/figures-of-the-week-africas-renewable-energy-potential/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2021/04/26/will-cannabis-legalization-reduce-crime-in-mexico-has-it-in-the-us/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2021/04/10/africa-in-the-news-updates-on-natural-resources-and-politics-in-niger-djibouti-benin-and-chad/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2021/03/26/africas-green-bond-market-trails-behind-other-regions/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2021/03/04/understanding-and-mitigating-climate-change-risks/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2020/12/09/business-as-usual-is-not-an-option-the-future-of-natural-resource-governance/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2020/11/25/delhi-the-worlds-most-air-polluted-capital-fights-back/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2020/11/23/around-the-halls-what-should-the-biden-administration-prioritize-in-its-climate-policy/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2020/11/19/to-ride-covid-19s-green-wave-governments-must-slash-fossil-fuel-subsidies/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2020/11/12/figure-of-the-week-africas-used-vehicle-market-and-the-environment/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2019/08/23/for-growth-and-well-being-climate-crisis-overshadows-all-else/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/fixgov/2020/06/28/oil-gas-and-mining-corruption-is-it-inevitable/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2020/09/28/global-warming-fires-and-crime-in-mexico-and-beyond/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2019/09/16/the-fight-to-contain-climate-change-implementing-paris-mobilizing-action/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2019/09/13/campaign-2020-what-candidates-are-saying-on-climate-change/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2018/06/01/one-year-since-trumps-withdrawal-from-the-paris-climate-agreement/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2021/03/01/recipe-for-a-green-recovery-carbon-taxes/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2021/02/25/seizing-opportunities-for-fuel-subsidy-reform/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/brown-center-chalkboard/2020/10/28/the-importance-of-clean-air-in-classrooms-during-the-pandemic-and-beyond/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2020/10/26/not-dried-up-us-mexico-water-cooperation/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2020/10/12/saving-the-vaquita-marina-and-the-urgency-of-this-fall/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2020/10/06/using-extractive-industries-data-for-better-governance/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2019/07/10/to-save-forests-think-beyond-the-trees/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/fixgov/2019/07/08/the-politics-of-methane/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2019/06/08/africa-in-the-news-new-environmental-policies-on-the-continent-zimbabwes-imf-stabilization-program-and-sudan-update/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2019/05/17/india-2024-a-green-india/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2019/04/25/the-critical-frontier-reducing-emissions-from-chinas-belt-and-road/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2019/04/24/new-data-on-governance-of-national-oil-companies-why-transparency-and-oversight-matter/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/education-plus-development/2019/03/28/why-captain-planet-should-have-been-a-woman/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/techtank/2021/11/16/how-technology-can-help-with-methane-regulation/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2020/06/16/reopening-the-world-to-prevent-zoogenic-pandemics-regulate-wildlife-trade-and-food-production/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2020/06/08/play-the-game-a-presidents-climate-quandary/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2020/05/11/wildlife-trade-in-mexico-conservation-and-pandemics/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2020/04/30/six-covid-related-deregulations-to-watch/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2020/04/23/covid-19-and-climate-your-questions-our-answers/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2020/04/22/global-solutions-to-global-bads-2-practical-proposals-to-help-developing-countries-deal-with-the-covid-19-pandemic/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2020/09/14/illegal-fishing-in-mexico-and-policy-responses/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2020/09/05/africa-in-the-news-mali-coup-mauritius-oil-spill-and-covid-19-updates/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2020/08/19/amid-covid-19-dont-ignore-the-links-between-poor-air-quality-and-public-health/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2020/08/07/uncommon-ground-the-impact-of-natural-resource-corruption-on-indigenous-peoples/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2020/08/05/the-controversy-over-the-grand-ethiopian-renaissance-dam/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/techtank/2018/05/31/catastrophic-risk-to-ecosystems-puts-biotechnology-fixes-on-the-table/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2018/05/29/transition-to-electric-vehicles-in-karnataka-and-india-whats-real-possible-and-missing-in-the-ecosystem/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/fixgov/2018/05/16/young-republicans-diverge-on-climate-policy/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2018/05/10/figures-of-the-week-access-to-affordable-sustainable-and-modern-energy-in-africa/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/social-mobility-memos/2018/04/21/earth-day-it-is-about-equity-as-well-as-the-environment/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/brookings-now/2018/04/20/on-earth-day-5-facts-about-environmental-policy-and-research/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2019/01/28/the-deforestation-risks-of-chinas-belt-and-road-initiative/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/fixgov/2018/12/20/what-frances-yellow-vest-protests-reveal-about-the-future-of-climate-action/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2021/11/10/infrastructure-in-the-developing-world-is-a-planetary-furnace-heres-how-to-cool-it/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2021/10/25/net-zero-carbon-pledges-have-good-intentions-but-they-are-not-enough/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2021/09/28/the-risks-of-us-eu-divergence-on-corporate-sustainability-disclosure/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2021/07/26/a-porpoise-to-serve-rescuing-the-vaquita-and-the-us-mexico-relationship/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2021/07/23/addressing-africas-extreme-water-insecurity/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2021/07/07/transnational-governance-of-natural-resources-for-the-21st-century/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2020/04/21/how-to-reduce-emissions-as-much-as-possible-at-the-lowest-cost/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/the-avenue/2020/04/14/weakening-environmental-reviews-for-transportation-infrastructure-is-a-bridge-too-far/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2020/02/18/why-ethiopia-egypt-and-sudan-should-ditch-a-rushed-washington-brokered-nile-treaty/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2020/07/30/the-evolution-of-the-eiti-and-next-steps-for-tackling-extractive-industries-corruption/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2020/07/23/a-master-class-in-corruption-the-luanda-leaks-across-the-natural-resource-value-chain/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2020/07/20/the-damage-trumps-wall-causes-in-mexico/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2020/07/10/what-the-pandemic-reveals-about-governance-state-capture-and-natural-resources/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2017/12/20/estimating-the-rising-cost-of-a-surprising-tax-shelter-the-syndicated-conservation-easement/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2021/07/02/protecting-forests-are-early-warning-systems-effective/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/fixgov/2021/06/24/when-climate-policy-works-hfcs-and-the-case-of-short-lived-climate-pollutants/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/brown-center-chalkboard/2021/05/19/now-is-the-time-to-invest-in-school-infrastructure/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/planetpolicy/2017/12/08/fill-the-gaps-in-the-tax-bill-with-a-carbon-tax-and-expanded-benefits-for-working-families/"},
{"Link": "https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2017/11/27/on-the-vices-and-virtues-of-trophy-hunting/"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `main_dict` it will have all data as key value pair as URL and text assosiate to it

```
main_dict={}
for page in range(1,10):
    dict_data={}
    print(page)
    res=requests.get(f"https://www.brookings.edu/topic/environment/page/{page}?type=posts")
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
    main_data=soup.find_all("h4",class_="title")
    lst=[]
    for i in main_data:
        url=i.find("a")['href']
        text=i.find("a").get_text(strip=True)
        dict_data[url]=text
    lst.append(dict_data)
    main_dict[page]=lst
```

Output:

```
{1: [{'https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2021/12/06/focac-2021-chinas-retrenchment-from-africa/': 'FOCAC 2021: China’s retrenchment from Africa?',
   'https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2021/12/06/back-to-the-future-climate-change-resilience-self-insurance-and-market-insurance/': 'Back to the future: Climate change resilience, self-insurance, and market insurance',
   'https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2021/12/06/what-biden-should-say-to-putin-on-ukraine/': 'What Biden should say to Putin on Ukraine',
...
```

Comment: My code in BeautifulSoup is working perfectly fine. I want to do the same thing in Scrapy. I want to know the approach I would have to go with to do the same thing using Scrapy.